# Show that $f(x)=\cos x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Tags: continuity

We have $|x_2-x_1|<\delta \implies |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\varepsilon$ so $|\cos x_1-\cos x_2|<\varepsilon$ how should I proceed after this? There is already an answer using Lipschitz and Mean value theorem but is there any way to do this question by not using them? Because in the book which I am using these topics are given after this question.

Comment: What do you mean “we have …”? That’s what you must prove.

Comment: hint: use the sum to product formula for $|cos(x1) - cos(x2)|$

Comment: ... in particular,$$\cos(x_1) - \cos(x_2) = 2\sin\left(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x_2 - x_1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry my english is not so good

Answer (score 2):

$cos(x)$ is continuous and is therefore uniformly continuous on compact intervals $[a,b]$. Therefore, it is uniformly continuous on $[0,2\pi]$. By periodicity, we get uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi can you solve using the method I mentioned?

Comment: @hariharan We are not doing your home work.

Comment: @KurtG. I dont want you to do my homework , like I said above I am stuck in THAT step and I want you guys to help in that.

Comment: @hariharan For an $~\epsilon, ~\delta~$ approach, note that if $~f(x) = \cos(x),~$ then $~|f'(x)| = |\sin(x)| \in [0,1].~$  Therefore, if $~0 < |x - a| < \delta,~$ then you should be able to show that $~|f(x) - f(a)| < \delta.~$  You mentioned that you wish to avoid the Mean Value Theorem.  Okay, look at the *proof* to the Mean Value Theorem, and (in effect) re-invent the wheel, incorporating the *proof* directly into your analysis.  The alternative strategy to proving the key point in the $~\epsilon, ~\delta~$ approach is to use the (easily proven) identity shown in Theo Bendit's comment.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you